# Automorphisms of anticanonical rational surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\pi\colon X\to\mathbb{P}^2$ be the blow-up of the projective plane at nine points in very general position. Is it true that ${\rm Aut}(X)$ is the trivial group?
If so, is there an easy argument to prove it?

Comment: Yes, it's true. I have to admit I don't know the details of the proof, but here is a reference: MR0563788 (81d:14020) Gizatullin, M. H. Rational G-surfaces. (Russian) 
Izv. Akad. Nauk SSSR Ser. Mat. 44 (1980), no. 1, 110–144, 239.

Comment: I should add that I don't have access to that paper, and the review doesn't make it clear that the paper contains the theorem the OP asked about: I'm going purely on the reference on page 3 of the paper MR2682184 (2011i:14034) Totaro, Burt. The cone conjecture for Calabi-Yau pairs in dimension 2. Duke Math. J. 154 (2010), no. 2, 241–263.

Answer (score 3):

Yes to your first question. See the paper

Koitabashi - Automorphism groups of generic rational surfaces.

As for your second question, whilst Kotabashi uses some standard techniques on the geometry of surfaces and abelian varieties, I would not personally say that his proof is "easy". I will let you form your own opinion on the matter.

Comment: Many thanks, Koitabashi paper is very clear.